# How to set datetime in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Is there any way to change SQL server datetime? GETDATE() and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP show the wrong dates.

I read that SQL reads the date from the server settings where the SQL instance is installed. But on this server(Windows SERVER 2019) time, date and timezone are correct.
Only in SQL Server are those settings wrong. I've tried to find a solution for this issue over internet but I couldn't find any.

Only SYSUTCDATETIME() shows correct information.

Comment: Post your system date/time and the output of those date/time functions in SQL Server that you've mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

`GETDATE()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will be working correctly. They return the server's **local** time. If the time is "wrong" then it's because the time on the server is "wrong"; most likely because it thinks it's in a different timezone to where it physically is or has the wrong DST setting.

Clearly, however, the time is correct on the server for its location (in the sense of that if it's observing CET it would display 11:38 around now) as you state that `SYSUTCDATETIME()` returns the correct UTC time.

if the server *does* have the wrong time setting, however, the fix is fix the time on the server. Speak to your server administrator about that. YOu change change the values `GETDATE()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  return as they are based on the host's time. This is why I am confident the time is correct, likely it is either set to the wrong timezone or DST setting as the UTC time is correct.

If, however, the time *is* correct for where the server is **physically** located, then the answer is don't use `GETDATE()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to get the value for *your* local time, instead (like you have) use `SYSUTCDATETIME()` or `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` and then convert the time to *your* timezone in the application layer.

Comment: Time on physically server is Correct. Not it's 19:29 but sql returns 10:29.

Comment: It's no option to not use getdate becouse third part ERP systems use this date in that way. I can't change the way they use it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the server timezone was changed since the SQL Server instance was started. Run the query below to verify the timezone SQL Server is currently using:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMEZONE();
```

If the result is different than the OS configuration, restart the SQL Server instance for the new timezone to become effective.

Comment: Unfortunately this command doesn't work. Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'CURRENT_TIMEZONE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: I also restarted SQL instance. No effect.

Comment: @AndrzejŁukasiak, what SQL Server version are you running? I assumed SQL 2019. The timezone offset should be one of the first messages in the SQL Server error log.